# Turns Black When Saved

Tags: rendering

So I'm trying to render a logo for something that I'm working on. However, when I save the picture, it is just shown as black when I go to where it's located. When I save anything outside of Blender, it works fine, but Blender is different. Can you help me?

[image: An example]

Comment: Is your logo in black color and has alpha?

Comment: My logo is in black, but I don't know the alpha thing. I put the background transparent.